# Streaming Live Video From Webcam Android

Tags: android, opencv

I need to stream live video from web-cam to my android phone. On PC side I am planning to use OpenCV and grab each frame using [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html) class. I am familiar with OpenCV, but no idea about how to stream this video to Android. I need to do this through wifi.  Can any one suggest how can I do this ?. Or is there any other method for doing this ?.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Via file transfer is easy.. But I've totally no idea on live stream

Comment: Hi thanks for replay...Can you give some link which help me for doing these.

Answer (score 1):

Via file transfer, it is easy to read video files.
Here's the answer from [another post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337505/android-capture-video-frame), and [one more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497595/cvcapturefromavi-problems-opencv-android)

The code in that post is as follows.

```
public static Bitmap getVideoFrame(FileDescriptor FD) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(FD);
        return retriever.getFrameAtTime();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that this is off-line process. For online realtime transfer, I have no idea.